# Bulk memory free of fragmented stl containers

Tags: c++

Currently, when we want to destruct a very large nested list/map of complex objects with very fragmented memory allocations, I assume C++ is to invoke destructors and free the memory one by one and recursively which takes lots of time and is inefficient?

In my case, I find it sometimes takes 1 min or more to destruct a 300GB object.

The operating system can kill a process taking lots of memory efficiently because it just free all the memory without considering much about the logic inside process.

I am wondering if there is any existing library for C / C++ can do just that? To provide a customized memory allocator maintaining an id system?
Such that if I specify an id to create an allocator for a given large STL container (and its elements). When I want to destruct it, I can free all the memory allocated with a specified id, and just discard the pointer to the outer container (and it will skip all the destructors) ? Just like we can "kill" a pid...

Thanks!

Comment: The operating system just unmaps the virtual memory pages, it's relatively fast. What the operating system does not do, is invoke any destructor or even run any of your code. If you're dealing with such large data then you probably should use your own custom allocators to allocate large swathes of memory from the OS and handle the local allocations internally without bothering the OS. You could even make it so that when you're done, and constructors doesn't have to run, you skip the destruction of the objects and just free/unmap that large chunk of memory.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude yes, that is what I mean. just wondering if there is any existing library? We just don't want to reinvent/remake the wheel

Comment: We use pools and custom allocators then just free the entire pool and not individual objects. Should your question be tagged C? Seems like it shouldn't.

Comment: Can you post or otherwise share this code? I'd like to see it in action to see what the issue is. (If it's really an allocator-related issue and not just due to destructors touching random memory, I'd be interested in trying it out.)

Comment: Possible solution: jemalloc comes with arena support (memory pool). By overriding C++ new operator to use the mallocx function of jemalloc with a flag to use specific arena. Creating an arena and switching to the arena before insert elements to the container and switching back to default after insertion. Destroy the arena when no longer needed

Comment: @RetiredNinja Thanks! Pure C library is possible to solve this problem. For example, like you said if a malloc library has a function switching the default memory pool the malloc will use

Answer (score 2):

This can be done through a pool allocator and placement new, of course you will have some limits, like finding a common size for your slot in the pool (if you don't want fine granularity) but in general a simple case scenario as the following:

```
struct Foo {
  double x, y;
  Foo(double x, double y) { this->x = x; this->y = y; };
};

std::byte* buffer = new std::byte[sizeof(Foo) * 10];

Foo* foo1 = new(buffer) Foo(1.0, 2.0);
Foo* foo2 = new(buffer + sizeof(Foo)) Foo(1.0, 2.0);

delete[] buffer;
```

explains the basic principle. This must be done with precautions though, since no one is calling your destructor (and you should do it manually through `foo1->~Foo()`). But if the destructor has no side effects or you can take care of them at once then you are allowed by the standard not to explicitly call it.

Now the tricky part is the fact that if you are using STL collection then they internally do a lot of allocations to store their needs (especially containers like `std::map` or `std::list`). So you'd need to write a custom [`allocator<T>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/Allocator) which wraps an efficient pooling scheme.

Comment: Thanks! But a good memory allocator is not so straight-forward to write and maintain. Passing customized allocator around and deep into every nested container is too complicated... overriding new operator could also do the trick but some new global variable is needed, and it is hacky. So I was expecting if there is already a library for this.

Comment: Overriding new operator is not hacky at all and it's used a lot, especially in game development where pool allocators are rather common.

Answer (score 0):

If you want efficient `freeing` of memory, doing a single delete is the way to go. Though keep in mind that freeing the memory ain't the only thing done by the delete call. It also calls a destructor. If not trivial or not visible, your compiler still has to call it via a function call.

That said, use `std::vector` where possible. I've already written custom sets and maps on top of vector, with less functionality (no removing), to gain memory and performance.

If you have a lot of small objects, like a vector that usually takes 1, 2, ... 16 elements, you can gain speed by using more memory. The [boost small vector and other containers](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/master/doc/html/container/non_standard_containers.html) can help you to not allocate. Using this in algorithms, already saved me remarkable percentages (>90%) on real world code.

Finally, you can't always win. If you can estimate the memory usage, or already something close by, you can use the [https://howardhinnant.github.io/stack_alloc.html](stack allocator of Howard Hinnant). Don't be fooled by the name, you can also allocate the memory on the heap. With a few manipulations, I suspect you should be able to change it to accept a runtime size instead. It ain't perfect, though, you could cover a big part.

That said, you can always create a memory leak on purpose, though that might remove the side effects of the destructor. You could [extract the nodes](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/extract) out of your map, and store them in an allocated vector. This might be leaping into UB, I'm not an expert on that.

Oh, and finally, you could inherit from the standard allocator, and only override the deallocate function. Look at a global to decide if you want to call the actual deallocate. Flip the switch, and do the memory leaking at exit.